# Export data from Facebook to Google accounts

Tags: facebook

My Android phone is linked with both my Google and Facebook accounts. Many of my friends' email addresses are available only in Facebook account details. Is there any way (perhaps an app) to copy the account information (like email address) to the contact details in Google?

I am aware that exporting is not allowed from Facebook now, but there is a possibility of having some applications in Google Play Store which can copy details of merged contacts.

Answer (score 1):

I had done a bit of a research on this.

There was a trick until a few months back, by linking the Facebook account to Yahoo account so that the contacts get merged. Later it was possible to export the contact details from Yahoo.

But now even this method doesn't seem to work, as exporting the contacts will only export Yahoo contacts and not the one merged from Facebook. :(